# linux command line only download from web page that requires interaction using wget

Tags: linux, download, wget

certain pages require confirmation(eg. check a checkbox to accept agreement) prior to download
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html

is it possible to download this from linux command line(no x server available)?

I use wget to directly download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a console only text web-browser, use [lynx](http://lynx.browser.org/) or [links](http://www.jikos.cz/~mikulas/links/)

If you want to script interaction, consider [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html) (and also [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/), which is interfaced to many scripting languages, e.g. `python` etc).